# Unit Tests Failure At Xcode 3.2.4, iOS 4.1 SDK Using Hamcrest Assertion

Tags: iphone, xcode, hamcrest

We upgraded to Xcode 3.2.4 with iOS 4.1 SDK, now our tests are failing.

First because of this **An internal error occurred when handling command output: -[XCBuildLogCommandInvocationSectionRecorder endMarker]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x201aa7200** then we used the patch suggested by apple forums (http://gist.github.com/586296) and now the test fail on the first Hamcrest assertion.

```
NSNumber * c1 = ...
NSNumber * c2 = ...
assertThat(c1, is(c2))
```

Here's the log:

```
-[NSCFNumber conformsToProtocol:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2116890
2010-09-30 22:10:23.153 otest[21063:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber conformsToProtocol:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2116890'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x004e3b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x002d840e objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x004e56ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x004552b6 ___forwarding___ + 966
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x00454e72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
 5   OCHamcrest                          0x00ccd17b HC_wrapInMatcher + 52
 6   OCHamcrest                          0x00ccb4e1 HC_is + 41
 7   UnitTests                           0x030870c9 -[MyTest testMethod] + 141
 8   CoreFoundation                      0x004545cd __invoking___ + 29
 9   CoreFoundation                      0x004544a1 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 145
 10  SenTestingKit                       0x2010464a -[SenTestCase invokeTest] + 69
 11  SenTestingKit                       0x20104d1f -[SenTestCase performTest:] + 192
 12  SenTestingKit                       0x2010444b -[SenTest run] + 88
 13  SenTestingKit                       0x20106fa7 -[SenTestSuite performTest:] + 115
 14  SenTestingKit                       0x2010444b -[SenTest run] + 88
 15  SenTestingKit                       0x20106fa7 -[SenTestSuite performTest:] + 115
 16  SenTestingKit                       0x2010444b -[SenTest run] + 88
 17  SenTestingKit                       0x20106871 +[SenTestProbe runTests:] + 174
 18  otest                               0x000023b3 0x0 + 9139
 19  otest                               0x000025de 0x0 + 9694
 20  otest                               0x00002086 0x0 + 8326
 21  otest                               0x00002035 0x0 + 8245
 22  ???                                 0x00000003 0x0 + 3
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
/Developer/Xcode3.2.4/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include: line 415: 21063 Abort trap              "${THIN_TEST_RIG}" "${OTHER_TEST_FLAGS}" "${TEST_BUNDLE_PATH}"
/Developer/Xcode3.2.4/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:451: error: Test rig '/Developer/Xcode3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest' exited abnormally with code 134 (it may have crashed).
```

Any one see that before? it was working perfectly on 3.1.3 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed, by using the latest OCHamcrest as a static library instead of a framework and add  -lstdc++ to other linker flags.

Hope that save someone time.

Comment: I just released the 1.0 version, which is even easier to set up.